# How can I solve the problem ' Windows stopped working'?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I've been coding a problem in C. It compiled successfully, but when I ran it after getting the inputs, it shows a pop up as "Windows stopped working. I'm pretty sure that the problem is with my code. Can you please help me?
The problem is to find the number of pairs in the array whose sum is divisible by the given number(k). For example, ar={1,2,3,4,5,6} and k=5. The number of pairs that meet the criteria is 3 i.e, [1+4],[2+3],[4+6]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,k,i,a[100],*ptr1,*ptr2,*ptr3,sum=0,d,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    ptr1=a;
    ptr2=a;
    ptr3=a+n-1;
    while(ptr2!=ptr3){
        if(ptr1==ptr2){
            ptr1++;
        }
        sum=*ptr1+*ptr2;
        d=sum%k;
        if(d==0){
            count++;
        }
        ptr1++;
        if(ptr1==ptr3){
            ptr2++;
            ptr1=a;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}
```

Comment: Single step through the program with your debugger and watch where those pointers point at every step along the way.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: This code can't let _Windows_ stop working. Unless you named your program "Windows".

Comment: It isn't clear what your code is doing? Can you explain a bit? I am pretty sure ptr1 must be going out of bounds and causing error

Comment: You indefinitely increment `ptr1` until it gets out of bounds. Do what the first comments tells you to do and/or rethink the algorithm. What is the program supposed to do? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: “Windows stopped working” is a message Microsoft Windows gives when a process hangs. I think the specific trigger may be that its message queue is full so that the system cannot deliver a new message (such as a message that a key has been pressed while input focus is on one of its windows).

Comment: @Jabberwocky , I've edited the question.. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Abhishek I've edited it.. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil My knowledge isn't sufficient to understand what you're saying. But I think you can help me solve this. I've edited my question. Would you recommend doing any changes?

Comment: What do you expect with `ptr3 = a + n - 1`? Isn't `a` array here?

Comment: @SharonShelton: I am sorry, your code is just kind of a mess. It is hard to know what you intend the various lines to mean. If you step through it in a debugger or add suitable `printf` statements to show how the program is executing, you will see that it iterates `ptr1` beyond the end of the array. You should rewrite the loops.

Comment: @SharonShelton hint: don't work with pointers but with array indexes. But the truth is, your code is a real mess....

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I'm sorry.. I'm not a good coder. I'm a student. I'm trying to improve myself. Thank you

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm sorry. I'm not that good at coding. I'll try to solve it. I'm sorry for bothering you. Thank you